# How can I convert an Integer to localized month name in Java?

Tags: java, date, locale

I get an integer and I need to convert to a month names in various locales:

Example for locale en-us:
1 -> January
2 -> February

Example for locale es-mx:
1 -> Enero
2 -> Febrero

Comment: Watch out, Java months are zero-based so 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb, etc

Comment: you are right, so if a need to change the language, just need to change the locale. Thanks

Comment: @NickHolt **UPDATE** The modern [`java.timeMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum is one-based: 1-12 for January-December. Ditto for [`java.time.DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html): 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per ISO 8601 standard. Only the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar` have crazy numbering schemes. One of many reasons to avoid the legacy classes, now supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
public String getMonth(int month) {
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
}
```

Comment: Do you not need 'month-1', since the array is zero based ? atomsfat wants 1 -> January etc.

Comment: He does need month-1, because the month is the 1-based month number which needs to be converted to the zero-based array position

Comment: This works too, you need to construct DateFormatSymbols with the locale though.

Comment: public String getMonth(int month, Locale locale) {


    return DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale).getMonths()[month-1];
}

Comment: _HE_ needs `month-1`. Anyone else using `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` will just need `month`

Comment: DateFormatSymbols implementation was changed in JDK 8, so getMonths method doesn't return correct values for all Locale's anymore: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html

Comment: and does anyone know the way to convert from name to int?

Comment: [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) is part of the terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Now supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: I have written this extension for Kotlin developers.
fun Int.toMonthName(): String {
    return DateFormatSymbols().months[this]
}

Comment: While it works in English locale, in Russian it returns genitive name: `января` instead of `Январь`. Also have in mind that months are in range 1..12.

Answer (score 46):

## tl;dr

```
Month                             // Enum class, predefining and naming a dozen objects, one for each month of the year. 
.of( 12 )                         // Retrieving one of the enum objects by number, 1-12. 
.getDisplayName(
    TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , 
    Locale.CANADA_FRENCH          // Locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in localizing. 
)
```

## java.time

Since Java 1.8 (or 1.7 & 1.6 with the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)) you can use this:

```
Month.of(integerMonth).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, locale);
```

Note that `integerMonth` is 1-based, i.e. 1 is for January. Range is always from 1 to 12 for January-December (i.e. Gregorian calendar only).

Comment: let's say you have the String Month of May in french using the method you posted (May in french is Mai), how can I get the number 5 from this String??

Comment: @usertest I wrote a rough-draft class `MonthDelocalizer` in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39220766/642706) to get a `Month` object from a passed localized month name string: `mai` → Month.MAY. Note that case-sensitivity matters: In French, `Mai` is invalid and should be `mai`.

Comment: It's 2019. How is this not the top answer?

Comment: Not work for me. The result is not the name of the month, but the number of the month. You need to use `TextStyle.FULL` to work.

Comment: @Dherik I believe this is a JDK bug. `TextStyle.FULL` and `FULL_STANDALONE` are both defined to return "full **text**", see [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/TextStyle.java#L92-L100). What language do you use? In my language (Slovak) `FULL` gives the month name in genitive, which is good when used in a full date. `FULL_STANDALONE` gives it in nominative, which is good e.g. for choosing in a listbox.

Comment: @Oliv, agree with you that `FULL` returns month name in genitive (Russian locale). But when use `FULL_STANDALONE` it returns number in any locale. At least, in Android with Compose library.

Comment: @CoolMind that's a JDK bug, report it.

Answer (score 36):

You need to use LLLL for stand-alone month names. this is documented in the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation, such as:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "LLLL", Locale.getDefault() );
dateFormat.format( date );
```

Comment: JDK 1.7 / `IllegalArgumentException : Illegal pattern character 'L'`

Answer (score 16):

I would use SimpleDateFormat.  Someone correct me if there is an easier way to make a monthed calendar though, I do this in code now and I'm not so sure.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public String formatMonth(int month, Locale locale) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", locale);
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: These terrible classes are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 14):

Here's how I would do it.  I'll leave range checking on the `int month` up to you.

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

public String formatMonth(int month, Locale locale) {
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(locale);
    String[] monthNames = symbols.getMonths();
    return monthNames[month - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Using SimpleDateFormat.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public String formatMonth(String month) {
    SimpleDateFormat monthParse = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    SimpleDateFormat monthDisplay = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    return monthDisplay.format(monthParse.parse(month));
}


formatMonth("2");
```

Result: February

Answer (score 8):

Apparently in Android 2.2 there is a bug with SimpleDateFormat.

In order to use month names you have to define them yourself in your resources:

```
<string-array name="month_names">
    <item>January</item>
    <item>February</item>
    <item>March</item>
    <item>April</item>
    <item>May</item>
    <item>June</item>
    <item>July</item>
    <item>August</item>
    <item>September</item>
    <item>October</item>
    <item>November</item>
    <item>December</item>
</string-array>
```

And then use them in your code like this:

```
/**
 * Get the month name of a Date. e.g. January for the Date 2011-01-01
 * 
 * @param date
 * @return e.g. "January"
 */
public static String getMonthName(Context context, Date date) {

    /*
     * Android 2.2 has a bug in SimpleDateFormat. Can't use "MMMM" for
     * getting the Month name for the given Locale. Thus relying on own
     * values from string resources
     */

    String result = "";

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    try {
        result = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month_names)[month];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        result = Integer.toString(month);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: _"Apparently in Android 2.2 there is a bug"_ — It would be useful if you could link to where the bug is tracked.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
Month.of( yourMonthNumber )           // Represent a month by its number, 1-12 for January-December. 
  .getDisplayName(                    // Generate text of the name of the month automatically localized. 
      TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE ,    // Specify how long or abbreviated the name of month should be.
      new Locale( "es" , "MX" )       // Locale determines (a) the human language used in translation, and (b) the cultural norms used in deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and so on.
  )                                   // Returns a String.
```

## `java.time.Month`

Much easier to do now in the java.time classes that supplant these troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum defines a dozen objects, one for each month.

The months are numbered 1-12 for January-December.

```
Month month = Month.of( 2 );  // 2 → February.
```

Ask the object to generate a String of the [name of the month, automatically localized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-).

Adjust the [`TextStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to specify how long or abbreviated you want the name. Note that in some languages (not English) the month name varies if used alone or as part of a complete date. So each text style has a `…_STANDALONE` variant.

Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

- Which human language should be used in translation.
- What cultural norms should decide issues such as abbreviation, punctuation, and capitalization.

Example:

```
Locale l = new Locale( "es" , "MX" );
String output = Month.FEBRUARY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE , l );  // Or Locale.US, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH.
```

---

## Name → `Month` object

FYI, going the other direction (parsing a name-of-month string to get a `Month` enum object) is not built-in. You could write your own class to do so. Here is my quick attempt at such a class. *Use at your own risk*. I gave this code no serious thought nor any serious testing.

Usage.

```
Month m = MonthDelocalizer.of( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).parse( "janvier" ) ;  // Month.JANUARY
```

Code.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

// For a given name of month in some language, determine the matching `java.time.Month` enum object.
// This class is the opposite of `Month.getDisplayName` which generates a localized string for a given `Month` object.
// Usage… MonthDelocalizer.of( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).parse( "janvier" ) → Month.JANUARY
// Assumes `FormatStyle.FULL`, for names without abbreviation.
// About `java.time.Month` enum: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html
// USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. Provided without guarantee or warranty. No serious testing or code review was performed.
public class MonthDelocalizer
{
    @NotNull
    private Locale locale;

    @NotNull
    private List < String > monthNames, monthNamesStandalone; // Some languages use an alternate spelling for a “standalone” month name used without the context of a date.

    // Constructor. Private, for static factory method.
    private MonthDelocalizer ( @NotNull Locale locale )
    {
        this.locale = locale;

        // Populate the pair of arrays, each having the translated month names.
        int countMonthsInYear = 12; // Twelve months in the year.
        this.monthNames = new ArrayList <>( countMonthsInYear );
        this.monthNamesStandalone = new ArrayList <>( countMonthsInYear );

        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= countMonthsInYear ; i++ )
        {
            this.monthNames.add( Month.of( i ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , this.locale ) );
            this.monthNamesStandalone.add( Month.of( i ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , this.locale ) );
        }
//        System.out.println( this.monthNames );
//        System.out.println( this.monthNamesStandalone );
    }

    // Constructor. Private, for static factory method.
    // Personally, I think it unwise to default implicitly to a `Locale`. But I included this in case you disagree with me, and to follow the lead of the *java.time* classes. --Basil Bourque
    private MonthDelocalizer ( )
    {
        this( Locale.getDefault() );
    }

    // static factory method, instead of  constructors.
    // See article by Dr. Joshua Bloch. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151
    // The `Locale` argument determines the human language and cultural norms used in de-localizing input strings.
    synchronized static public MonthDelocalizer of ( @NotNull Locale localeArg )
    {
        MonthDelocalizer x = new MonthDelocalizer( localeArg ); // This class could be optimized by caching this object.
        return x;
    }

    // Attempt to translate the name of a month to look-up a matching `Month` enum object.
    // Returns NULL if the passed String value is not found to be a valid name of month for the human language and cultural norms of the `Locale` specified when constructing this parent object, `MonthDelocalizer`.
    @Nullable
    public Month parse ( @NotNull String input )
    {
        int index = this.monthNames.indexOf( input );
        if ( - 1 == index )
        { // If no hit in the contextual names, try the standalone names.
            index = this.monthNamesStandalone.indexOf( input );
        }
        int ordinal = ( index + 1 );
        Month m = ( ordinal > 0 ) ? Month.of( ordinal ) : null;  // If we have a hit, determine the `Month` enum object. Else return null.
        if ( null == m )
        {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException( "The passed month name: ‘" + input + "’ is not valid for locale: " + this.locale.toString() );
        }
        return m;
    }

    // `Object` class overrides.

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;

        MonthDelocalizer that = ( MonthDelocalizer ) o;

        return locale.equals( that.locale );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return locale.hashCode();
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Usage example:
        MonthDelocalizer monthDelocJapan = MonthDelocalizer.of( Locale.JAPAN );
        try
        {
            Month m = monthDelocJapan.parse( "pink elephant" ); // Invalid input.
        } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e )
        {
            // … handle error
            System.out.println( "ERROR: " + e.getLocalizedMessage() );
        }

        // Ignore exception. (not recommended)
        if ( MonthDelocalizer.of( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).parse( "janvier" ).equals( Month.JANUARY ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "GOOD - In locale "+Locale.CANADA_FRENCH+", the input ‘janvier’ parses to Month.JANUARY." );
        }
    }
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin Extension**

```
fun Int.toMonthName(): String {
    return DateFormatSymbols().months[this]
}
```

**Usage**

```
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).toMonthName()
```

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue when you use DateFormatSymbols class for its getMonthName method to get Month by Name it show Month by Number in some Android devices. I have resolved this issue by doing this way:

In String_array.xml

```
<string-array name="year_month_name">
    <item>January</item>
    <item>February</item>
    <item>March</item>
    <item>April</item>
    <item>May</item>
    <item>June</item>
    <item>July</item>
    <item>August</item>
    <item>September</item>
    <item>October</item>
    <item>November</item>
    <item>December</item>
    </string-array>
```

In Java class just call this array like this way:

```
public String[] getYearMonthName() {
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.year_month_names);
        //or like 
       //return cntx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month_names);
    } 

      String[] months = getYearMonthName(); 
           if (i < months.length) {
            monthShow.setMonthName(months[i] + " " + year);

            }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM", new Locale("en", "US"));
    System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
}
```

Comment: this looks like to be the proper answer, but can you explain what you do and why you do it this way?

Comment: I do this way because I think is simple and not complex !

Comment: It uses the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class, though.

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

Just inserting the line

```
DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths()[view.getMonth()]
```

will do the trick.

Comment: [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) is part of the terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Now supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: This Answer duplicates the content of [the accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038580/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this a very simple way and call it like your own func

```
public static String convertnumtocharmonths(int m){
         String charname=null;
         if(m==1){
             charname="Jan";
         }
         if(m==2){
             charname="Fev";
         }
         if(m==3){
             charname="Mar";
         }
         if(m==4){
             charname="Avr";
         }
         if(m==5){
             charname="Mai";
         }
         if(m==6){
             charname="Jun";
         }
         if(m==7){
             charname="Jul";
         }
         if(m==8){
             charname="Aou";
         }
         if(m==9){
             charname="Sep";
         }
         if(m==10){
             charname="Oct";
         }
         if(m==11){
             charname="Nov";
         }
         if(m==12){
             charname="Dec";
         }
         return charname;
     }
```

Comment: No need to write this kind of code. Java has built-in [`Month::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)).

Comment: No need to write this boilerplate code. Check my answer posted above.