# Converting month into MMM format

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to convert my month into the MMM format using SimpleDateFormat but i am unable to convert it.

```
    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);

    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

    int tempyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int tempmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int tempday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String month = new Integer(tempmonth).toString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works (I just tested it)

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
int tempmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

SimpleDateFormat newformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
SimpleDateFormat oldformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

        String monthName = null;
        Date myDate;
        try {
            myDate = oldformat.parse(String.valueOf(tempmonth));
            monthName = newformat.format(myDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("MMM", monthName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using the format you created. Try:

```
String month = format.format(tempmonth);
```

You can format the whole date at once with:

```
String dateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), would make such things easier.

Anyway, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038570/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-localized-month-name-in-java) question here has several answers.