# How to formate sql date to Simple date formate in java,android?

Tags: java, android, sql, date

```
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(
    jObject.getString(AppConstants.KEY_COMMENT_DATE)
);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM YYYYY");
try {
    simpleDateFormat.parse(
        jObject.getString(AppConstants.KEY_COMMENT_DATE)
    );
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am having date in `2015-03-05 03:20:13` format from webservice, I want to format and separate out month, year and other all.

Comment: use simple date format

Comment: But how idont know coding flow..
I am getting number formate exception
Thanks

Comment: Post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date = df.parse("2015-03-05 03:20:13");
```

Comment: I used this and using date object i called date.getMonth().but it is throwing  unparsable date i.e. parse exception

Comment: Make the H capital in date format string ..see above I have edited in my answer.

Comment: Is there any way to get name of month from month no. like 1-> January...???I studied util and date library long before...thanks

Comment: @ArthTilva , take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038570/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-localized-month-name-in-java

Comment: java.util.date will give you month no from 0-11 if you want to get the full month initiate one more Simpledateformate instance with format string MMMM then use method sdf.format(date)