# Can't convert int month to month name android java

Tags: java, android, datepicker, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert int month to month name(string). I am using simple date format but I get only "Jan" for all months. why is this happening?

```
 public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        String sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("LLL", Locale.getDefault()).format(monthOfYear);

    String date = +dayOfMonth+" "+(sdf);
    dateTextView.setText(date);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an Integer to localized month name in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038570/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-localized-month-name-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get only "Jan" for all months

Because `String sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("LLL", Locale.getDefault()).format(monthOfYear);` here, `monthOfYear` is Number Object so, `DateFormate` class will convert it to `Date` object from that number, which will be between `1 Jan, 1970` to `12 Jan, 1970` so you are always getting Jan for all month.

Try,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("LLL", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.getTime());

 or

sdf = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths()[monthOfYear];
```

DateFormat code snippet:

```
     /**
     * Formats the specified object as a string using the pattern of this date
     * format and appends the string to the specified string buffer.
     * <p>
     * If the {@code field} member of {@code field} contains a value specifying
     * a format field, then its {@code beginIndex} and {@code endIndex} members
     * will be updated with the position of the first occurrence of this field
     * in the formatted text.
     *
     * @param object
     *            the source object to format, must be a {@code Date} or a
     *            {@code Number}. If {@code object} is a number then a date is
     *            constructed using the {@code longValue()} of the number.
     * @param buffer
     *            the target string buffer to append the formatted date/time to.
     * @param field
     *            on input: an optional alignment field; on output: the offsets
     *            of the alignment field in the formatted text.
     * @return the string buffer.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *            if {@code object} is neither a {@code Date} nor a
     *            {@code Number} instance.
     */
    @Override
    public final StringBuffer format(Object object, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
        if (object instanceof Date) {
            return format((Date) object, buffer, field);
        }
        if (object instanceof Number) {
            return format(new Date(((Number) object).longValue()), buffer, field);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad class: " + object.getClass());
    }
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of the `DateFormatSymbols` class. Very handy. I think you want `getShortMonths()`, though.

Comment: @MikeM you are right getShortMonths() is right method to use for this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleDateFormat#format()` method has an overload that takes an `Object`, which is why you're able to pass an `int` to it. However, this is not the method you want. You want the one that takes a `Date` object, which we can get from a `Calendar` with the appropriate month set:

```
private String getMonthAbbr(int monthOfYear) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("LLL").format(c.getTime()); 
}
```

Passing `Locale.getDefault()` is redundant in this case, as that is what `SimpleDateFormat` will use if it's not specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Month.of( yourMonthNumber ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
```

## `java.time.Month`

Much easier to do now in the java.time classes that supplant these troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum defines a dozen objects, one for each month.

The months are numbered 1-12 for January-December.

```
Month month = Month.of( 2 );  // 2 → February.
```

Ask the object to generate a String of the [name of the month, automatically localized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-). Adjust the [`TextStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to specify how long or abbreviated you want the name. Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to say which human language should be used in translation and what cultural norms should decide issues such as abbreviation, punctuation, and capitalization.

```
String output = Month.FEBRUARY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.