# Get month name from month number for a series of numbers

Tags: java

I need to find a balance months in my table. I did in numeric form, but I need in alphabetic form like "January, February". Please help

```
    int lastpaid = Integer.parseInt(s); **//this is i am getting from my database**
    int currentmonth = m; **// this is from georigian Calender**
    int[] arr = new int[12];
    int[] month = new int[12];
    int count = 0;

    for(int j=currentmonth;j>=lastpaid+1;j--)
    {
       arr[count] = j;
       count++;
    }


    for(int k : arr)
    {
        if(k == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

        month[count] = k;

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, you found it but need it in text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an Integer to localized month name in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038570/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-localized-month-name-in-java)

Comment: bro i get output like  (5,4,3,2) (4,3,2) etc i want to convert and show in alphabetic form

Comment: What you are describing is just a simple mapping of integer to string. If 1 then January, etc... Not sure why you are thinking this is so much more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get `String` description of a month from `int` using 1) array of month or 2) own method.

Case 1:

```
String[] monthString = new String[]{"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Later, in the code, you can call it like:
EXAMPLE:

```
 for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {
       System.out.println("Month: "+monthString[i]);
    }
```

Assuming, we have case when we need to get month some times  (5,4,3,2);

```
...(monthString[5], monthString[4], monthString[3], monthString[2]) ..
```

Case 2:

```
   public String getMonth(int month){
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        return monthString;
    }
```

EXAMPLE:

```
   for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {
       System.out.println("Month: "+getMonth(i));
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Month: January
Month: February
Month: March
Month: April
Month: May
Month: June
Month: July
Month: August
Month: September
Month: October
Month: November
Month: December
```

Comment: Why so complex? public String getMonth(int month) { String[] monthNames = {"", "Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec"}; return monthNames[month]; }

Comment: Of course, we can use an index of the array to get appropriate value, but I think this example can be good too. 
When you have (5,4,3,2) you can get: (monthNames(5), monthNames(4), ..)

Comment: plz show me some example i cant understand what to do

Comment: case 1 is printing every thing in three times

Comment: Please, check it once (yes, because I didn't complete the string full)

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
Month.of( 5 ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )
```

> May

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. The `Month` enum provides an object for each month of the year. You can retrieve each by a number. Then ask the `Month` name to generate a localized string for name of that month.

```
int[] monthNumbers = { 5,4,3,2} ;
for ( int monthNumber : monthNumbers ) {
    Month month = Month.of( monthNumber );  // Get a month for number, 1-12 for January-December.
    String monthName = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc.
    System.out.println(monthName);
}
```

When run.

> May
>
> April
>
> March
>
> February

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).